# How to inject dependency in HiltWorker?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to inject my repository in a `CoroutineWorker` annotated like `@HiltWorker` - after I have followed all the steps in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager) I'm get this error when trying to inject the repository:

> 2023-03-02 14:54:08.570 13936-14117 WM-WorkerFactory
> it.gabtamagnini.visualstock          E  Could not instantiate
> it.gabtamagnini.visualstock.utils.LicenseWorker
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> it.gabtamagnini.visualstock.utils.LicenseWorker. [class
> android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
> at
> androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:145)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 2023-03-02 14:54:08.571
> 13936-14117 WM-WorkerWrapper        it.gabtamagnini.visualstock
> E  Could not create Worker
> it.gabtamagnini.visualstock.utils.LicenseWorker

The Worker looks like this:

```
@HiltWorker
class LicenseWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val repository: LicenseRepository
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        // TODO: check if the license if still valid and if so return Result.success() else Result.failure()
        return try {
            val license = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                repository.getLicense()
            }
            Log.i("License", license.id)
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```

Application:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
}
```

That happens not only with that repository but with any dependency I try to inject.

If I remove all the dependencies and return only a `Result.success()` it will work without any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a dependencies issue as I have had only: `kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")` in my `build.gradle`.

To solve the issue I have had to add even `kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")`

[As per documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager)